# On making a new script " StackTrace: wapi_shm_file_open: shared file [File_Name] open error: Permission denied" appears

Tags: macos, unity-game-engine

**Specs**
Macbook,
Unity 5.2.4

**Procedure:**
1. Create Unity project and save it on desktop
2. Create Scene
3. Create a script

**Result:**
Error as follows

> Stacktrace: wapi_shm_file_open: shared file
>   [/Users/accountname/.wapi/shared_data-Muttahirs-MacBook-Pro.local-Darwin-x86_64-312-12-0]
>   open error: Permission denied

When I delete the script it gets back to normal, i.e. not stacktrace error.

This was not happening in Unity 5.1.3

Comment: You have macbook, I should not ask, but I'd, do you have any antivirus or firewall installed?

Comment: Can you read the file inside the unity inspector? That would indicate that there's atleast the permission to read. Any weird file or user permissions on your desktop? If that's reproducable, go post it in the Unity Bugtracker.

Comment: Hamza: No. I have even deactivated the firewall and checked. It is something to do with Unity 5.x. Because Unity 4.x is running perfectly fine in my laptop.

Comment: Maximallion: It is ".wapi" file, which is hidden. One has to open it via terminal. I have already reported the Bug on Unity BugTracker, but no response till yet.
The weird thing is, Unity 4.x is running perfectly fine, but not Unity 5.x

Comment: Hamza Hasan: Yes I have a macbook retina 8GB RAM core i5, there is not firewall or antivirus installed

Comment: Maximilian Gerhardt: Nothing as such, the file opens properly. Now there is a new issue, till making the project its fine, as soon as I create a script in the project, the project hangs forever

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstalling Unity3D clears this issue.